# Temporary failure in name resolution,mongo-sec:27017

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to connect to a remote mongodb server using `pymongo`, but I am getting error. The connection works in `Studio3T`. I am behind VPN, but I am sure the issue is not related with it otherwise the connection via `Studio3T` wouldn't work either. The error I am getting is

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongo-arb:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution,mongo-sec:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution,mongo-sec2:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution,mongo:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 62ea25815b38c5f0b06416d3, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('mongo', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongo:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')>, <ServerDescription ('mongo-arb', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongo-arb:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')>, <ServerDescription ('mongo-sec', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongo-sec:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')>, <ServerDescription ('mongo-sec2', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongo-sec2:27017: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')>]>

This is the code I am using

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient("mongodb://remote_server_ip:27017/")
client.server_info()
```

Comment: Seems like you have a replicaset with 2 nodes and an arbiter, don't you? Not sure how robomongo suppress the error. Must be due to the difference in drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was pymongo version issue.. Version 3.12 worked for me

```
python3 -m pip install pymongo==3.12
```

Comment: Latest version of pymongo won't work but can confirm 3.8.0 does

Answer (score 1):

For those who're using pymongo 4 version, need to explicitly set `directConnection` as `True` in MongoClient options.

More information here https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrate-to-pymongo4.html#directconnection-defaults-to-false